# Что делать с большим кол-ом параметров

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api, firebase

У меня для маркера(ов) много параметров такие как title, subtitle, snipper, tags, position. + Эти маркеры у меня встречаются во многих фрагментах. Стоит ли/правильно ли выносить эти параметры в модель(если да, то потом как правильно к ним обращаться)?

P.S. В будущем планирую перенести их в БД Firebase.

Comment: Ну конечно а почему нет? Вы же будете их хранить в базе. А таблица - уже реляционная модель останется только объектную прикрутить!

Answer (score 1):

Ну пока у Вас так понимаю нет хранилища и Вы просто хотите жанглировать модельками между классами. Здесь в принципе и обращаться можно просто напрямую, но когда уже будет база, то я бы создал какой-то класс поверх этой базы для того чтобы унифицировать все вызовы к базе и переправить их через этот класс. Чтобы потом было проще менять базу.

Поясню, допустим у Вас есть класс SomeDatabase и метод в getAllMarkersFromDB(), Вы поверх класса который работает с базой, пилите еще один класс, называете его допустип MarkersRepository и уже ему метод добавляешь getAllMarkers(), а в этом методе зовешь SomeDatabase#getAllMarkersFromDB().
Везде в коде у себя работаете с классом MarkersRepository. Это такая себе инкапсуляция, если захотите потом поменять БД, то просто перепишете метод getAllMarkers() и не нужно будет по всему проекту что-то менять.
Описание конечно сложное получилось, но на практике делать попроще.